# Using classpath when debugging groovy scripts

Tags: groovy, classpath

I'm new to Java and Groovy, and this is a really simple question on how to use `classpath` when debugging groovy scripts.

I setup my Groovy project according to https://gist.github.com/tknerr/42258e761f2a0f95a92b:

```
$ find src
src
src/main
src/main/groovy
src/main/groovy/impl
src/main/groovy/impl/FooImpl.groovy
src/test
src/test/groovy
src/test/groovy/main.groovy

$ head src/main/groovy/impl/FooImpl.groovy src/test/groovy/main.groovy
==> src/main/groovy/impl/FooImpl.groovy <==
package impl

class FooImpl {
        def foo() {
                "hello?!"
        }
}

==> src/test/groovy/main.groovy <==
println new impl.FooImpl().foo()
```

And I have already build everything:

```
$ find build/classes
build/classes
build/classes/groovy
build/classes/groovy/main
build/classes/groovy/main/impl
build/classes/groovy/main/impl/FooImpl.class
build/classes/groovy/test
build/classes/groovy/test/main.class
```

My goal is to use existing classes in `classpath` without packaging them into `.jar` file each time when debugging my groovy scripts, but am wondering why I'm getting the following errors:

```
cd src/test/groovy

$ ls ../../../build/classes/
groovy

$ groovy --classpath ../../../build/classes/ main.groovy
.../src/test/groovy/main.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class impl.FooImpl 
 @ line 1, column 9.
   println new impl.FooImpl().foo()
           ^

1 error
```

Same with `groovysh`.

How can I make it working?

Comment: Your classpath must be `build/classes/groovy/main` so `impl/FooImpl.class` overlaps with the package.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick, my real project is setup according to https://github.com/nickmcdowall/JavaAndGroovy, i.e., it is setup to use Groovy and Java interchangeably. So how can i specify build/classes/groovy/main and build/classes/java/main at the same time?

Comment: Got it. `--classpath ../../../build/classes/groovy/main:../../../build/classes/java/main`

Comment: Yes, the `--help` from `groovy` does not make that clear at all - but it's the same as with java. Use a path-separator list. And maybe another thing: unless you want to learn things here, you are most likely better off using a build tool like maven, gradle, ...